# Creating an ActionLink and MapRoute that there is a constant name in it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, maproute

In my Asp.net MVC 5 (C#) project I want to create some links by @Html.ActionLink or every you know is better like:

> /Tags/Linq
>
> /Tags/SqlServer
>
> /Tags/MVC

That Tags is constant name and after that in the URL is tag name.For example like [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Tags/Linq)

In addition I want to pass a parameter such as Id but I don't want to show in the URL.

How can I do it?

And how should I write a suitable MapRoute for it?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example (don't forget to write it before default route):

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "Tags",
     "tags/{tagTerm}",
     new { controller = "Tags", action = "SearchTagResults" }
);
```

In addition (passing Id) use POST not GET.