# ASP.NET MVC Search Results Page MapRoute Doesn't Work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, maproute

How can i set mapRoute for search results page? My code doesn't work.

Global.asax.cs

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           name: "SearchResults",
           url: "{action}/{Keyword}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Search" }
       );
```

Search Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                @Html.TextBox("Keyword",null , new { @class = "SearchBox" })
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            }
```

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult Search(string Keyword)
    {
        GamesContext db = new GamesContext();
        var SearchResults= (from i in db.Games where i.GameName.Contains(Keyword) || i.GameDesc.Contains(Keyword) select i).Take(20).ToList();

        return View(SearchResults.AsEnumerable());
    }
```

Comment: do you want to get keyword value in get or post controller??

Comment: Now i am using get controller, but it doesn't matter. if it works i  can use post controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works for me (should be before default route):

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "SearchResults",
     "Search/{Keyword}",
     new { controller = "Search", action = "SearchAction" }
);
```

[Creating an ActionLink and MapRoute that there is a constant name in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234560/creating-an-actionlink-and-maproute-that-there-is-a-constant-name-in-it/25235044#25235044)

And there's a point to use new controller for search instead of home with this route.